# subset of array in golang

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, go

I am trying to write the equivalent of the following line in python

`H = [e for e in G if condition(e)]`

Here is my example code. Basically I am just trying to use a getter function (G.get) to get a subset of `G`. So I think I want `arr2` to be a new array but containing the same object.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Object struct {
    x int
}

type Group []Object

func (G *Group) get() (H []Object) {
    for _,v := range *G {
        H = append(H,v)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    arr := make(Group,1)
    arr[0].x = 1
    fmt.Println(arr)
    arr2 := arr.get()
    arr[0].x = 3
    fmt.Println(arr)
    fmt.Println(arr2)
}
```

Which compiles and runs and gives me

```
[{1}]
[{3}]
[{1}]
```

My question is "Why does `arr2` not contain the same instance of an Object as `arr`?" I believe I understand `make` only instantiates a `Group` thing which means it includes one `Object` in it. But then the for loop shouldn't create a new `Object` should it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simpler snippet of code shows what's going on:

```
var a Object
a.x = 1
b := a
fmt.Println(a, b) // prints {1} {1}
b.x = 2
fmt.Println(a, b) // prints {1} {2}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/lYWJTBbA-a)

The statement `b := a` copies the `Object` value in variable `a` to the variable `b`. There are now two copies of the value. Changing one does not change the other.

This is different from Python where assignment copies a reference to a value.

The loop in the question also copies the values:

```
for _,v := range *G {
    H = append(H,v)
}
```

The variable `v` is a copy the slice element from `*G`. A copy of `v` is appended to slice `H`. There are three independent Object values: the value in slice `*G`, the value in `v` and the value in slice `H`.

If you want the slices to all refer to the same `Object` value, then store pointers to `Object` values in the slice:

```
type Group []*Object

arr := make(Group, 1)
arr[0] = &Object{x: 1}
fmt.Println(arr[0].x)  // prints 1
arr2 := arr.get()
arr[0].x = 3
fmt.Println(arr[0].x)  // prints 3
fmt.Println(arr2[0].x) // prints 3
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/KStKQ2kMP8)

Comment: Great explanation! That is good to know about `:=` copying the value. Also, do you know if there is a better way to do `[e for e in G if condition(e)]`?